# Fluid width for my frames and CSS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my site :

[check revision history if you care]

As you can see the frame and the tabs content both are not fluid width.I want the height to be fixed.

Just that according to the window and resolution the width shoukd automatically set for both the "Tabs Content Frame" and the iFrame themselves..

Here is my standard frame ":

```
 <iframe name="wframe" width="980px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="1500px" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAMPLE_SEARCH" ></iframe>
```

Thanking You,
5416339

Comment: If you use Ctrl+U i think it should do it..Ant way i added it for you..

Comment: @[numberstring] the whole point of this site is to ask specific questions pertaining to programming, which in generally uses codes. It's very useful to us if you post your relevant code so we don't have to hunt for your broken elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 1 of `style.css` reads;

```
.container{width:995px;margin:10px auto}...
```

If I understand you correctly you wish the frame to have a fluid width? Simply change the `width:995px` to `width:100%`.

Also, your iFrames all have a `width` attribute set.

```
<iframe name="wframe" width="980px" ... /></iframe>
```

Also change `width="980px"` to `width="100%"`. (See lines 100, 111, 121, and 132 of your `web-search.phtml` template/file).